# display self closing xml elements to html output

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xquery, marklogic

My requirement is to display some `xml` elements (which are a part of input `xml`) in an `html` page.

for eg:

```
<org:specs>
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
</org:specs>
```

I want this entire `xml` snippet to appear as it is in the `html` output page, retaining the indentation followed in the input
Anyone has any idea on how to implement it using `XSLT` or `Xquery`?

EDIT: Jan 2nd, 2012

I tried the first solution(given below). It works, but i lost the indentation. 
Giving more details, the implementation in my case will be using `Xquery`. I will use Marklogic command `xdmp:xslt-eval(<Stylesheet>,<A-Xquery-function-retrieving-the-above-xml>)`. When I use the first solution, the resulting html page has no indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the browser, HTML doesn't preserve white space very well unless you start doing CSS, which isn't supported uniformly in browsers.  I do the following, which preserves white space on display and in the character serialization:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace org = "someorg";

let $xml := 
<org:specs>
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
</org:specs>


let $quote-options :=
<options xmlns="xdmp:quote">
  <method>xml</method>
  <indent>yes</indent>
  <indent-untyped>yes</indent-untyped>
</options>

return

<div><pre>
{xdmp:quote($xml, $quote-options)}
</pre></div>
```

Comment: great. this worked. are we always supposed to use <options> in the manner used here? why cant we add the options in  xdmp:quote directly?

Comment: You can certainly do it without the extra *let*.  I only put the options in a $quote-options variable for readability.

Answer (score 4):

**I. An easy way**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:org="some:org" exclude-result-prefixes="org">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="org:specs">
     <xmp>
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xmp>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided non-well-formed text made an well-formed XML document):

```
<t xmlns:org="some:org">
<org:specs>
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
</org:specs>
</t>
```

**produces**:

```
<xmp>
   <org:specs xmlns:org="some:org">
      <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
      <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
      <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
      <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
   </org:specs>
</xmp>
```

**and this displays in the browser in the wanted way**:

```
<org:specs xmlns:org="some:org">
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
</org:specs>
```

**II. Prety-looking, browser-displayed XML**

See the XSLT code of the **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** how this application produces such result.

**III. Generating all the required input for the browser as text** (`method="text"`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="textify"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[*]" mode="textify">
         <xsl:text>&amp;lt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="textify"/>
   <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" mode="textify"/>

         <xsl:text>&amp;lt;/</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
   <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*[not(node())]" mode="textify">
         <xsl:text>&amp;lt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="textify"/>
   <xsl:text>/></xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*" mode="textify">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" mode="textify">
  <xsl:call-template name="textify">
   <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="textify">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
   <xsl:variable name="vChar" select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$vChar = ' '">
       <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;#xA0;'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$vChar = '&#9;'">
       <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;#xA0;&amp;#xA0;'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$vChar = '&#xA;'">
       <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;br />'"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vChar"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:call-template name="textify">
   <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
    "substring($pText, 2)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), it produces the wanted result**:

```
&lt;org:specs><br />&#xA0;&#xA0;&lt;org:wild animal="6" species="land"/><br />&#xA0;&#xA0;&lt;org:fish animal="7" species="water"/><br />&#xA0;&#xA0;&lt;org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/><br />&#xA0;&#xA0;&lt;org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/><br />&lt;/org:specs>
```

**and it is displayed by the browser as**:

<org:specs>
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/>
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/>
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/>
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/>
</org:specs>

Comment: I tried the first solution. It works, but i lost the indentation. The implementation will be using Xquery. I will use Marklogic command xdmp:xslt-eval(<Stylesheet>,<A-Xquery-function-retrieving-the-above-xml>). When i use the first solution, the resulting html page has no indentation.

Comment: @user1119206: How could you try the first solution *with XQuery*, if this is an XSLT solution? Al three solutions I provided are XSLT -- not XQuery! And if the proprietory extensions you are using don't provide the necessary indentation, it is time to think about better XSLT implementations. Also, try the last solution -- it has all non-breaking soaces hardcoded, so the indentation cannot disappear.

Comment: Well, i can use your XSLT code in an X-query with the marklogic command i specified! Last solution looks good, but that is like manually introducing spaces. That may not be useful in my case. Thanks for responding !

Comment: @user1119206: Remove the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and try again.

Comment: I tried the same. It shows an empty space and I am not getting the elements on the html page. Though I could see them properly indented when I view its source.

Comment: @user1119206: This means that your browser doesn't display `<xmp>` as per HTML psec. As I said before, solution III should produce indented results in the browser (it produces them for me) -- try it.

Comment: I think <xmp> is actually deprecated. i tried with <pre> and used  xml equivalents for '<' and '>'. I still have the same problem. Indentation is not in place.

Comment: @user1119206:  As I said before, use solution III.

Answer (score 0):

The following works like a charm in MarkLogic CQ, using (an old) FireFox:

```
let $xml :=
<org:specs xmlns:org="some:org"> 
  <org:wild animal="6" species="land"/> 
  <org:fish animal="7" species="water"/> 
  <org:bird animal="8" species="trees"/> 
  <org:mammal animal="9" species="land"/> 
</org:specs> 

return

<html><body>
<h1>Org</h1>

<xmp>{$xml}</xmp>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure the xmp tag is supported by all browsers yet though. I used to take the 'textify' approach (putting it in a pre without the br tags) as suggested by Dimitre.

Comment: the <xmp> tag is deprecated. <pre> works like a gem. thanks for responding.

Comment: @satsamsk Ah, I assumed it was the other way around. I didn't even know it existed until I read it here.. :)